# calling command with some arguments works but not with others but works from console

Tags: go

The following code works and outputs details of 10 processes.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    print(top())
}

func top() string {
    app := "/usr/bin/top"

    cmd := exec.Command(app, "-n 10", "-l 2")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

    if err != nil {
        return err.Error() + " " + string(out)
    }

    value := string(out)
    return value
}
```

However, when I try the same with an additional argument of "-o cpu" (e.g. cmd := exec.Command(app, "-o cpu", "-n 10", "-l 2")). I get the following error.

```
exit status 1 invalid argument -o:  cpu
/usr/bin/top usage: /usr/bin/top
        [-a | -d | -e | -c <mode>]
        [-F | -f]
        [-h]
        [-i <interval>]
        [-l <samples>]
        [-ncols <columns>]
        [-o <key>] [-O <secondaryKey>]
        [-R | -r]
        [-S]
        [-s <delay>]
        [-n <nprocs>]
        [-stats <key(s)>]
        [-pid <processid>]
        [-user <username>]
        [-U <username>]
        [-u]
```

But the command "top -o cpu -n 10 -l 2" from my console works fine. Also I'm using OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: Have you tested `/usr/bin/top -o cpu -n 10 -l 2` in your console? Maybe the `top` you tested was not `/usr/bin/top`. You can check `which top` to know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate your arguments.

`top -o cpu -n 10 -l 2` is *not* what you are executing. What you're passing as arguments to the command is equivalent to using `top "-o cpu" "-n 10" "-l 2"` in a shell (which if you try, it will give you the exact same output).

Most commands will strictly parse that as 3 arguments. Since POSIX arguments don't require a space, `top` splits off the `-o` as the first option, and uses the rest as its argument. This works for the numerical arguments mostly by accident, but the for `-o` it looks for a field named `" cpu"`, which there isn't.

Instead, use

```
exec.Command(app, "-o", "cpu", "-n", "10", "-l", "2")
```

Comment: That works, thanks for explaining the numerical and string arguments issue as well.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is general unix behavior, not Go specific.